# xcode installation on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, macports

I bought a new mac (Lion), downloaded xcode, installed it, then found out it was version 3.2.x. I found out I could get the latest versions of all software from itunes. So, I started downloading (and installing) xcode 4.2.1 from itunes. Before it could finish, I uninstalled the older version using this command : sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

It worked except after xcode 4.2.1 didn't install properly. When I try to install macports, I get this message: xcode is not installed. When I go to itunes again, it displays "xcode installed", I cannot install it again! What should I do now?

Comment: Why don't you `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all` one more time and then try to reinstall it?

Comment: This is what I get when I try: sudo: /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found. devtools is already uninstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get Xcode from iTunes.  You get it from the Mac App Store.  Look in your /Applications folder for an app named "Install Xcode".  If it's there, run it.  If it's not, open the App Store from the Apple menu.  Type "Xcode" in the search box to find the app, and click the install button.  That will give you the "Install Xcode" app in your /Applications folder, which you can then run to really install Xcode.

Comment: sorry for the terminology. That worked, didn't know it added the installer in Application. Thanks.